# PHP synchronization

Tags: java, php, synchronization, erlang, sql-loader

I'm unsure of the best solution for this but this is what I've done.

I'm using PHP to look into a directory that contains zip files.

These zip files contain text files that are to be loaded into an oracle database through SqlLoader (sqlldr).

I want to be able to start more than one PHP process via the command line to load these zip files into the db.

If other 'php loader' processes are running, they shouldn't overlap and try to load the same zip file. I know I could start one process and let it process each zip file but I'd rather start up a new process for incoming zip files so I can load concurrently.

Right now, I've created a class that will 'lock' a zip file, a directory, or a generic text file by creating a file called 'filename.ext.lock'. Other process that start up will check to see if a file has been 'locked' in this way, if it has it will skip that file and move on to another file for processing.

I've made a class that uses a directory and creates 'process id' files so that each PHP process has an id it can use for logging purposes and for identifying which PHP process has locked the file.

I'm on a windows machine and it isn't in the plan to make this an ubuntu machine, for those of you that might suggest pcntl.

What other solutions do you see? I know that this isn't truly synchronized because a lock file might be about to be created and then a context switch occurs and then another PHP process 'locks' the file before the first one can create the lock file.

Can you please provide me with some ideas about how I can make this solution better? A java implementation? Erlang?

Also forgot to mention, the PHP process connects to the DB to fetch metadata about the files that it is going to load via SqlLoader. I don't think that is important but just in case.

Quick note : I'm aware that sqlldr locks the table it is loading and that if multiple processes try to load to the same table it will become a bottle neck. To alleviate this problem I plan on making a directory that will contain files name after tables that are currently being loaded. After a table has completed loading the respective file will be deleted and other processes will check that it is safe to load that table.

Extra information : I'm using 7zip to unzip the files and php's exec to perform these commands.

I'm using exec to call sqlldr as well.

The zip files can be huge (1gb) and loading one table can take up to an 1hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a .lock file, you can just rename the zip file when a loader start to process a zip file. e.g. "foobar.zip.bar", the process should be faster than creating a new file on disk.

But it doesn't ensure your next loader will be loaded after the file rename. You should at least have some 
controls loading new loaders in another script.

Also, just some side suggestion, its possible to emulate threading in PHP using CURL, you might want to try it out.

https://web.archive.org/web/20091014034235/http://www.ibuildings.co.uk/blog/archives/811-Multithreading-in-PHP-with-CURL.html

Comment: I don't want to use curl because it'll have to be a web server. I'd much rather stick with what I have now.

Comment: I liked this one best because each process can run concurrently without the others blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand right, but I have a suggestion: get the lock files with a prefix of priority.

Example:
*10-script.php* started

*20-script.php* started (enters a loop waiting for a *10-foobar.ext.lock*)

while *10-foobar.ext.lock* is not generated by *10-script.php*, still waiting

*30-script.php* will have to wait for *10-foobar.ext.lock* and *20-example.ext.lock*

I tried to find pcntl_fork with cygwin, but found nothing that works

Comment: I understand what you mean. For each new php process, if there is another process then assume that it will lock a file. Wait for that file to be locked BEFORE it tries to lock a file itself. Unfortunately I think this leads to the same problem because php does not have atomic actions. I think that that is what I need. What solutions can you think of that would be atomic and thus allow better synchronization?